# Running Django app in a server

Tags: python, django

I have created a simple hello world app in a server and would like to test it live. I'm using ssh to access the server, I have used the following commands to set it up: `django-admin startproject mysite`, and `python manage.py startapp site`.

Changed urls.py in "wrong" folder to:

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

and changed urls.py in "mysite" folder to:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^wrong/', include('wrong.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Now, when I test this in local server(my computer) through `python manage.py runserver` with "debug mode on", it works fine, but I'm clueless as to how this can be setup in a 'live' server?

I've used the migrate command to migrate everything, and I expected the "hello world" message to be displayed in the index page of my domain, but it didn't.

Can someone give me direction please, thanks in advance.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/deployment/

Comment: you need to setup a nginx or apache in the live server. Also you have to run django in a port and direct a http request to the domain to that port.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman: I've already been through the docs, its instructions are not specific and is not aimed at beginners. I'm clearly not a "web developer" and I'm trying to learn something here.

Comment: @almostabeginner can you tell me which command you run to start the server ?

Comment: @Trying2Learn I just checked and the server already has apache installed. It says apache2.

Comment: Sigh. There is full step-by-step documentation here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/ . You should go through that, and if you are having problems, you should post a *specific* question.

Comment: And if for some unknown reason that is not clear enough, there are literally hundreds of third-party tutorials on deploying with Apache.

Comment: @RajaSimon: The server is already running, I have not used any command. Thanks to "Trying2Learn", I actually have direction now, so I should be able to continue researching because I know the server has Apache2. I didn't get the rest of his comment, but I will research that too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django does not include a server for production purposes. You need to setup a webserver like Apache or Nginx. The documentation on the django website explains you how: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/deployment/

However, if your aim is to simply see a hello world message on your browser surfing to `http://example.com/` because you are trying out django, you CAN use the django built-in development server. But from what you posted, you won't see your message on your domain name address because:

1. The default address of the django dev server doesn't allow external access. You should use the command `./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` and then acces your server with this url: `http://example.com:8000/
2. Your urlconf is setup so that if you want to access the index view, you need to go to `http://example.com:8000/wrong/`. If you wanted to use only the domain and see the result of your view, you need to change your main `urls.py` like so:

   ```
   from wrong.views import index

   urlpatterns = [
       url(r'^$', index, name='index'),
       url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
   ]
   ```